# Two linear independent functions have zero Wronski

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are linear independent $C^1$ functions on $[a,b]$ and there Wronski det is zero, i.e.

$$fg^{'}-f^{'}g=0$$

Can we say there exists a point $t_0\in [a,b]$ such that:

$$f(t_0)=f^{'}(t_0)=g(t_0)=g^{'}(t_0)=0?$$

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From $fg'-f'g=0$, piecewise linear dependence seem to follow: $g(x)=c\cdot f(x)$, where $c$ is a constant.

$t_0\in [a,b]$ and $f(t_0)=0$ implies $g(t_0)=c\cdot f(t_0)=0$ and vice versa.
$t_0\in [a,b]$ and $f'(t_0)=0$ implies $g'(t_0)=c\cdot f'(t_0)=0$ and vice versa.
$t_0\in [a,b]$ and $f(t_0)=f'(t_0)=0$ implies $g(t_0)=g'(t_0)=0$ and vice versa.